# Splitting 2-Dim loop into multiple threads

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, 3d, uv-mapping

My algorithm computes the vertices of a shape in 3-dimensional space by using a 2-dimensional loop iterating over the U and V segments.

```
for (LONG i=0; i < info.useg + 1; i++) {
    // Calculate the u-parameter.
    u = info.umin + i * info.udelta;
    for (LONG j=0; j < info.vseg + 1; j++) {
        // Calculate the v-parameter.
        v = info.vmin + j * info.vdelta;

        // Compute the point's position.
        point = calc_point(op, &info, u, v);

        // Set the point to the object and increase the point-index.
        points[point_i] = point;
        point_i++;
    }
}
```

The array of points is however a one-dimensional array, which is why `point_i` is incremented in each loop. I know that I could compute the index via `point_i = i * info.vseg + j`.

I want this loop to be multithreaded. My aim was to create a number of threads that all process a specific range of points. In the thread, I'd do it like:

```
for (LONG x=start; x <= end; x++) {
    LONG i = // ...
    LONG j = // ...

    Real u = info.umin + i * info.udelta;
    Real v = info.vmin + j * info.vdelta;

    points[i] = calc_point(op, &info, u, v);
}
```

The problem is to calculate the `i` and `j` indecies from the linear point-index. How can I compute `i` and `j` when (well I think):

```
point_i = i * vsegments + j
```

I'm unable to solve the math, here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`point_i = i * vsegments + j` gives you:

```
i = point_i / vsegments
j = point_i % vsegments
```

Of course your loops actually do `segments + 1` iterations each (indices `0` to `segments`), so you would need to use `vsegments + 1` instead of `vsegments`

As a side note: Do you actually need to merge the loops into one for multithreading? I would expect the outer loop to have typically enough iterations to saturate your availible cores anyways.

Comment: Great, that works fine! Thank you :) The U segmentation may be 100, 1000 or 10k or more..., depending on the users needs. Same counts for the V segmentation.